# How to grep through rotated logs?

Tags: logs, apache-httpd

I want to know how many unique IPs have connected to my site. The following worked until logs started rotating:

```
cut -d' ' -f1 /var/log/apache2/access.log | uniq -d | wc -l
```

Is grepping through all the logs the idiomatic solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `grep` can take multiple files, but so can `cut`. Since you've already done it that way and it works, then you won't have to change anything other than put a glob in there that can catch all the log files that you need. Something like...

```
cut -d' ' -f1 /var/log/apache2/access*.log | uniq -d | wc -l
```

Comment: No, the asterisk is after "log": `cut -d' ' -f1 /var/log/apache2/access.log* | uniq -d | wc -l`

Comment: I don't have a crystall ball. :-)

Answer (score 1):

[zgrep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zgrep) is the tool [to read rotated logs](https://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/448-how-to-read-and-grep-compressed-rotated-log-files). It is installed by default on Ubuntu, Mint and Arch.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Count unique IPs.
zgrep -E [0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9] /var/log/apache2/access.log* | cut -d':' -f2 | cut -d' ' -f1 | uniq -d | wc -l
```